# try/except not catching future's TimeoutError

Tags: error-handling, timeout, python-3.6, python-asyncio, try-except

Could someone pls explain to me what’s going on here ?
I wanted to add a message to the timeout error:

```
future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(do_stuff(), loop=loop)
try:
    return future.result(timeout=3)
except TimeoutError:
    raise TimeoutError("Time out occurred while doing stuff")
```

`future.results()` (concurrent.futures._base.py) looks like this :

```
def result(self, timeout=None):
    # bla bla bla
    else:
        raise TimeoutError()
```

However when the timeout occurs my try/except clause doesn’t catch the Timeout. In fact

```
future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(do_stuff(), loop=loop)
try:
    return future.result(timeout=3)
except Exception as e:
    log.error(str(e))
```

shows empty `e`. WTH?

Comment: empty `e`: because `TimeoutError` is created without any arguments `TimeoutError()`. There's really no need for them, the fact that it errored is enough of an indication about what went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

OK. I know. I should be using `except asyncio.TimeoutError:`, not the base `TimeoutError`.